How to fix problem with connecting to DB from python?
I am trying to connect to postgres using python (postgres in Docker):
import psycopg2

DB_CONFIG = {
       'dbname': 'transport',
       'user': 'myuser',
       'password': 'mypassword',
       'host': 'my_postgres',
       'port': '5432',
       'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
       'options' : '-c client_encoding=UTF8'
   }

def con():
       try:
           return psycopg2.connect(**DB_CONFIG)
       except Exception as e:
           print(f"Error connecting to database: {e}")

print(con())
   

but I get the error:
Error connecting to database: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 56: invalid continuation byte

How to fix it?


Repeating the client_encoding option is not necessary. 2) Setting the client_encoding to UTF8 is not going to help if the client is not actually using UTF8. Confirm what the encoding is in use where the client is running. 3) Add to your question, as text: a) Postgres version. b) psycopg2 version. c) OS and version where the Python script is running.

